# Show empty cells in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the jquery fullcalendar plugin (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). I am trying to build a room reservation system. Currently I am struggling with a view in which I want to show the empty cells.

For example, if i have room1 booked on the dates 1,2,3,4,5 and room2 on 5,6,7,8,9 of the month, then it should show room1 in the dates 6 to 30 and room2 in 1 to 4 and 10 to 30 in the month. I am able to show the availability correctly (which means that the rooms would show up on the dates when they are booked), but i couldn't find anything to display the opposite.

Am I stuck with sending the whole events array of the unbooked room dates or is there another cleaner way here? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show only availability (days when room is not booked), just prepare method which return appriopriate set of date. For example that function should get start and end date as parameters, check availability in database and generate list of periods for every room within start and end date when particular room is available.